# Requested API is not supported in Admin On-Behalf-Of mode

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have recently started getting a 401 response with "Requested API is not supported in Admin On-Behalf-Of mode" when calling certain Microsoft endpoints. Specifically,

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/{channelId}/messages/{messageId}
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/joinedTeams
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams

However this one works

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

Some information about the setup:

1. We are using a token with delegated scopes
2. The token has the required permissions:

   AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All
   ChannelMessage.Send Chat.Create Chat.Read Chat.ReadWrite
   ChatMember.ReadWrite Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Sites.Read.All
   Sites.ReadWrite.All Team.ReadBasic.All User.Read User.Read.All
   User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite.All profile openid email
3. This has previously worked with the same token
4. This is happening on the v1.0 and beta endpoints
5. We tried removing admin consent from each scopes but still faced the
   same issue

I cannot find any information in the MS documentation regarding Admin On-Behalf-Of mode and wondered if anyone could shed any light on what we could be doing wrong?

**Further Update.**

We have now been able to reproduce this on a tenant and has to do with external guest users. These users are able to authenticate into the tenant but you cannot use the token obtained to call some of the Graph API endpoints - Anyone know why this is?

We have tried changing all the settings in External Identities in AAD but still getting the same response on the Graph API endpoints

Comment: Has anything changed about the user on behalf of whom those requests are being made? Is this a regular user in the tenant? Can you share an example of the full error response from Graph?

Comment: This user is an external guest user. Response from Teams: `"{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Requested API is not supported in Admin On-Behalf-Of mode.","innerError":{"date":"2022-09-08T15:08:22","request-id":"fc8072ca-193f-47aa-yyyy-xxxxxxxx","client-request-id":"fc8072ca-193f-47aa-yyyy-xxxxxxxx"}}}"`

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret - I assume that "Admin On-Behalf-Of mode" is a special case of normal on-behalf-of mode (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow). From that article, somewhere in the codepath it's failing with respect to guest users and the error message means that the token _should_ work from an access permissions standpoint but doesn't.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT I believe the "admin on behalf of" the error message speaks  of is delegated administration for CSP partners ([this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/partners-offer-delegated-administration-26530dc0-ebba-415b-86b1-b55bc06b073e)), which Teams doesn't support. It appears the external user here is being misidentified as a partner admin (even though they probably aren't). I've forwarded this to some folks in the Teams teams and they're looking into it.

Comment: @Philippe Signoret We have a similar issue with external guest users not being able to use certain endpoints and wonder if the two are related and additional work is required - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74475099/microsoft-graph-api-the-initiator-is-not-a-member-of-the-roster-in-the-generic)