# Microsoft Graph API - The initiator is not a member of the roster in the generic thread

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have a direct chat created between 2 users on Microsoft Teams with the following channel ID format:

19:[user1_user_id]_[user2_user_id]@unq.gbl.spaces

This was created using an application token with Chat.Create scope. The 2 users are an externally invited user (guest) and a normal member.

We can successfully see the channel details and membership roster when using the application token via

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/19:xxx_yyy@unq.gbl.spaces

and

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/19:xxx_yyy@unq.gbl.spaces/members

We have a valid access tokens for user1 (external guest) with the delegated scopes:

AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All Channel.Create Channel.ReadBasic.All ChannelMessage.ReadWrite ChannelMessage.Send **Chat.Create Chat.Read Chat.ReadWrite ChatMember.ReadWrite** Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Group.ReadWrite.All Sites.ReadWrite.All Team.ReadBasic.All User.Read User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All profile openid email

However, when trying to send a message to the chat using the external guest users delegated token we get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-11-11T21:10:19",
      "request-id": "d0d367cf-2f24-4f4b-9649-cce60ced7ccc",
      "client-request-id": "d0d367cf-2f24-4f4b-9649-cce60ced7ccc"
    }
  }
}
```

We then tried to fetch the channel details which worked. However membership roster or trying to get a message in the channel with external users delegated token returns the following response:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/19:xxx_yyy@unq.gbl.spaces/members

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "{\"errorCode\":209,\"message\":\"{\\\"subCode\\\":\\\"AclCheckFailed\\\",\\\"details\\\":\\\"The initiator 28:app:[tenantid]_[appclientid] is not a member of the roster c8b8b0db-ed80-5f80-a235-45rrdfgs06c5 in the generic thread 19:[user1id]_[user2id]@unq.gbl.spaces\\\",\\\"errorCode\\\":null,\\\"errorSubCode\\\":null}\",\"standardizedError\":{\"errorCode\":209,\"errorSubCode\":1,\"errorDescription\":\"AclCheckFailed-The initiator 28:app:[tenantid]_[appclientid] is not a member of the roster c8b8b0db-ed80-5f80-a235-45rrdfgs06c5 in the generic thread 19:[user1id]_[user2id]@unq.gbl.spacess\"}}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-11-11T22:58:50",
            "request-id": "dbd10850-db71-41bc-86c7-0b2d8debe710",
            "client-request-id": "dbd10850-db71-41bc-86c7-0b2d8debe710"
        }
    }
}
```

We were expecting that the delegated token could be used for these endpoints considering it has the correct scopes and the user is a guest of the channel.

We believe this is related to the external user and ACL Permissions similar to a previously resolved post ([Requested API is not supported in Admin On-Behalf-Of mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73705274/requested-api-is-not-supported-in-admin-on-behalf-of-mode)) but required work to be done internally at Microsoft.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue is now resolved. The delegated token can be used to fetch and post messages.